# CentOS doesn't see python3.8 after installing

Tags: python, linux, bash, installation, centos

I've installed the last version of Python with help this tutorial: https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-python-on-3-on-centos/

"Which" see python3.6 but doesn't see python3.8

```
[nikolay@nikovm ~]$ which python3.6
/bin/python3.6
[nikolay@nikovm ~]$ which python3.8
/usr/bin/which: no python3.8 in (/home/nikolay/.local/bin:/home/nikolay/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin) 

[nikolay@nikovm ~]$ python3.8
bash: python3.8: command not found  

[nikolay@nikovm ~]$ python3.6
Python 3.6.8 (default, Nov 21 2019, 19:31:34)
[GCC 8.3.1 20190507 (Red Hat 8.3.1-4)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>     

[nikolay@nikovm ~]$ ls /usr/local/lib
libpython3.8.a  pkgconfig  python3.6  python3.8
[nikolay@nikovm ~]$  

[nikolay@nikovm ~]$ ls /bin/ | grep python
python3
python3.6
python3.6m
unversioned-python

[nikolay@nikovm ~]$ ls /usr/bin/ | grep python
python3
python3.6
python3.6m
unversioned-python
```

Old version python (3.6) works.

I've reinstalled python3.8 many times, but it still doesn't work.

Help me please)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default on CentOS python 3.8 is installed into /usr/local/bin which occording to your output of "which" it is not in your path.

> (/home/nikolay/.local/bin:/home/nikolay/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin)

See if the python3.8 and other 3.8 binaries are within /usr/local/bin

If so add it to your path

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

then try again.